# Picture Rebus from another dimension

Tags: visual, rebus

[image: im1][image: im2][image: im3]

Hint:

> It's nothing to do with the US presidency

Comment: I think it may not be the best idea to use Trump in this puzzle because it may spark arguments unrelated to either this site or this rebus. But I am unable to edit it because I do not understand the nature of the image in the puzzle. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Parzival; its fine, don't worry about it...

Comment: ok, just a thought, but you do see where I'm coming from.

Comment: @Parzival; no. its not political - if i changed it to chairman mao it wouldn't fit the rebus

Comment: Hey, you should mark the correct answer on this one.

Comment: @question_asker; sorry didn't realize anyone had got it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is it

> Armageddon?

Because

> Arm + Aged (man) + Don(ald)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Old man strong versus old man dumb?

since

> the pictures show: 1. strength   2. old man   3. dumb man

Comment: hmmmm, no it isn't

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> Old MacDonald had a farm.

Because:

> Picture 2: Old, Picture 3: Donald, Picture 1: f(arm)

Comment: I admit it is a longshot...:-)

Comment: nice but completely wrong

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> Power before age

Because:

> Strength comes before age, and it trumps it!